# why are my newly added faces shaded

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

[image]
I am editing a model, however the faces that I added with F are shaded. Other faces are just plain color.

Comment: maybe recalculate the normals (Shift N), or maybe some inner faces or overlapping vertices?

Comment: @moonboots Its u again! Thank you. I got it done by select all (a key) then shift N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to inverted normals, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.